# Convert an asp.net application to IIS7 integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-2.0

What steps I need to perform in order to convert asp.net 2 application from IIS7 classic to integrated mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a process:
[Rick Strahl's blog](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/6075.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Nothing really.  ASP.NET 2.0 applications will run just as they have in IIS 6.0.  If you want to take advantage of any of the new features then you just need to update your code.  But unless you are changing the structure of the header of the response or intercepting requests for other applications you probably will not need to do anything.